# How can I use mpirun with a master and a slave node which are both Docker containers on different machines?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mpi

Let's say we have two machines, A and B, on the same local network. Their IP addresses are 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2, respectively, for the sake of this argument. The firewalls on both machines have been set up to allow connections at all ports. We verify that A can connect to B using SSH and vice versa.

We will use (almost) the same `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files to deploy containers on A and B. The `Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM danieldv/hode:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN service ssh restart

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

RUN cat /dev/zero | ssh-keygen -q -N ""
RUN echo 'Host *\n    Port 2222' >> ~/.ssh/config

EXPOSE 22
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

And the `docker-compose.yml` file contains:

```
version: "3"
services:
  dc_test:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
      - "10000-10100:10000-10100"
    environment:
      MPICH_PORT_RANGE: "10000:10100"
    extra_hosts:
      - "master:10.0.0.1"
      - "slave:10.0.0.2"
    hostname: master
```

Where we will replace 'master' with 'slave' on computer B. Note that the base container, `danieldv/hode:latest`, is a container I have built myself (available on Docker Hub) which has MPICH installed (as well as a bunch of other things I often use which are not relevant for this question).

Note that we use port `2222` to SSH into the containers on A and B to avoid conflicts with port `22` on their respective host computers. Note also that we forward ports in the range `10000:10100` and restrict MPI to only use ports in this range for connections.

We start the container on B first by running

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

from B.

Then we build and log into the container on A by running

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose run dc_test bash
```

from A.

Next, we send the ssh public key from `master` to `slave` using `ssh-copy-id slave` from the shell of the `master` container. We verify that we can log into `slave` from `master` using `ssh slave`.

Finally, we run `mpirun -hosts master,slave hostname`. The expected output from this command is:

```sh
master
slave
```

save from the order. However, the output I actually get is:

```sh
master
[proxy:0:1@slave] HYDU_sock_connect (utils/sock/sock.c:172): unable to connect from "slave" to "master" (Connection timed out)
[proxy:0:1@slave] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:185): unable to connect to server master at port 10000 (check for firewalls!)
```

What can I do to make this setup work? Or is what I'm trying to do simply not possible? If it is, would someone please give me a detailed working example?